# How do I check whether an object's ID is present in an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, logic

Here's the logic I'm trying to write, but I can't find the proper Ruby way to say it:

```
if Object.id [occurs in this array ->] [13, 16, 234]
   #run this code if true
else
   #run this code if false
end
```

Basically I want to return true if an id occurs somewhere in a specific array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for [Array#include?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F):

```
if [13, 16, 234].include? Object.id
    #run this code if true
else
    #run this code if false
end
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

#### Use Array#include?

One way to do this is to turn the logic around and query the array, rather the instance object, for inclusion using the [Array#include?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) method. For example:

```
[13, 16, 234].include? my_object.id
```

This will return a boolean value, which you can plug into your branching logic.